# git fatal error when pushing md file to Github

Tags: github, push, fatal-error

This is driving me crazy. I'm running git on mac osx 10.10.3

I keep getting "does not appear to be a git repository" message when trying to upload an MD file to github, here's what I get:

git push origin master
fatal: 'github.com/bbenavides/datasciencecoursera.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Any help appreciated thank you.

[The repository in question](https://github.com/bbenavides/datasciencecoursera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your remote isn't configured properly. You can view your configured remotes with

```
git remote -v
```

GitHub remotes generally look like

- `git@github.com:user/repo.git` for SSH connections (note the `git@` and `:`), or
- `https://github.com/user/repo.git` (note the `https://`) for HTTP connections

Your remote appears to be an HTTP remote without the protocol portion.

To update your remote (assuming its name is `origin`; you can see this in the output of `git remote -v` from before):

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/bbenavides/datasciencecoursera.git
git remote set-url --push origin https://github.com/bbenavides/datasciencecoursera.git
```

It's usually best to copy the URL directly from GitHub, which helps to prevent these kinds of typos.